# How can I return multiple values in a DLL-safe way in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, return-value

I would like to return multiple values in a cross DLL-safe way in C++.

Should I use a stuct/class ?

Comment: Think you need to explain your deep problem with the DLL side - specifically that memory allocated by the DLL needs to be released by the DLL - is that correct?

Comment: @Elemental  That seems to be a common myth, but new'ing in one dll and deleting in another doesn't cause a problem if the link is done correctly.

Comment: Actually it does if the DLL was built: on a different compiler, has custom new's, was built on the same compiler with different settings. I've battled with this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is not very clear however, here are a few hints:

1. A class/struct is meant to group things. Although a struct meant for grouping all the return values can be made but it really depends on how closely related those return values are. This is more a matter of adhering to conventions and OOP principals.
2. To return multiple values, you can use pointers and references. e.g., following function prototype returns a bool in a conventional way but accepts two pointers as parameters. The objects to which these pointers point to can be changed in the callee function and hence, multiple values can be returned.

**Function Prototype:**

```
bool returnValues(int i, char* c, int* result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PIMPL](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) idioms:

In header (dll safe surface):

```
class Type;

class MyClass
{
public:
  int GetNumberOfType();
  Type * GetValue(int i) { return this->values[i]; };
protected:
  Type ** values;
};
```

In Source:

```
#include <Type.h> // common header to real definition and declaration
```